# A question about $k_{\alpha \beta}:=\eta_{\mu \nu}L^{\mu}_{\alpha}L^{\nu}_{\beta}-\eta_{\alpha \beta}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames

I have a question in the book "A First course in string theory" by Zwiebach. In page 20, the auther says $$k_{\alpha \beta}x^{\alpha}x^{\beta}=0\tag{2.42}$$ must hold for all values of the coordinates $x$, we find that $$k_{\alpha \beta}+k_{\beta \alpha}=0,\tag{2.43}$$ where $$k_{\alpha \beta}:=\eta_{\mu \nu}L^{\mu}_{\alpha}L^{\nu}_{\beta}-\eta_{\alpha \beta}.\tag{2.42}$$ Why is that and how we conclude that $k_{\alpha \beta}=0$?

**My try:** $k_{\alpha \beta}$ is symmetric. In fact, we have $k_{\beta\alpha}=\eta_{\mu \nu}L^{\mu}_{\beta}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}-\eta_{ \beta\alpha}$. Since $\eta$ is symmetric, we have $k_{\beta\alpha}=\eta_{\nu\mu }L^{\mu}_{\beta}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}-\eta_{ \alpha\beta}$. If $L^{\mu}_{\beta}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}=L^{\nu}_{\alpha}L^{\mu}_{\beta}$, then we have $k_{\beta\alpha}=\eta_{\nu\mu }L^{\nu}_{\alpha}L^{\mu}_{\beta}-\eta_{ \alpha\beta}=k_{\alpha \beta}$. But why $L^{\mu}_{\beta}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}=L^{\nu}_{\alpha}L^{\mu}_{\beta}$?

If $k_{\alpha \beta}$ is symmetric, then from $k_{\alpha \beta}+k_{\beta \alpha}=0$ we have $k_{\alpha \beta}=0$. But why $k_{\alpha \beta}+k_{\beta \alpha}=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^{a}x^{b}= x^{b} x^{a}$ and $k^{ab}=k^{[a,b]}+k^{\{a,b\}}$, where $k^{[a,b]}= k^{ab}-k^{ba}$ and $k^{\{a,b\}}= k^{ab}+k^{ba}$.

From these decomposition, we easily see $k^{[a,b]} x^{a}x^{b}=0.$ This is in general.

Then, if $k^{ab} x^{a}x^{b}=0 $ is satisfied for all $x, $ we can say $$^\forall x,\ k^{\{a,b\}} x^{a}x^{b}=0.$$

This is almost equivalent to $k^{\{a,b\}}=0$.